# Sklearn package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Recently I have upgraded my sklearn package in Python 3.7 and after that I could not find some important packages like gridsearch() , cross_validation() , GaussianNb () etc .
I am a beginner in Machine learning and I want to continue working with Python 3 instead of using Python 2.  Can anyone please help me with this problem ? BTW, I use Anaconda 3 and Spyder 3.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Are you using correct virtual environment?

Comment: What do you mean 'cannot find some packages'. You actually can't use it, or is your editor giving an import warning? That can happen with e.g. PyCharm but your code will work fine nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create python 3.7.2 environment, then I could import  gridsearch() , cross_validation() , GaussianNb ()  methods that you have described in the question.

Note: There are multiple ways in which you can install sklearn. One of the popular way to do it is using conda package manager.

The following is working on Windows-10 OS. I am creating python 3.7 as conda virtual environment.

I am pretty sure, this must work on other OS(Linux, redhat). But I havent tested.

My steps.

Created the virtual environment.

```
>>> conda create --name Py37Test python=3.7 pandas scikit-learn
>>> import sklearn
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
```

[image]